# Python Dataframe convert each cell-string to a list type and explode

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe consists lists as cells. I run into the issues when I `explode` it. I understood that the list is stored inside the cell as `str` type not `object` type.
My code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[str([1,2])],'B':[str([10,20])]})

xdf
        A         B
0  [1, 2]  [10, 20]

xdf.apply(pd.Series.explode)

        A         B
0  [1, 2]  [10, 20]
```

Desired output:

```
xdf = 
   A   B
0  1  10
0  2  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xdf.applymap(eval).apply(lambda x: x.explode())
```

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice#:~:text=The%20point%20of%20all%20this,t%20need%20to%20use%20it.)

Comment: The OP's data is already in a 'bad' state in which the list data is represented as strings. If the above code fails, it means there is a problem with the upstream job that generated the input data.

Answer (score 1):

use the below code that

```
import pandas as pd
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[str([1,2])],'B':[str([10,20])]})
xdf.applymap(lambda x:x.strip("][").split(",")).apply(lambda x:x.explode())
```

1)by removing symbols and split we convert the STRING LIST to normal list
2)then we explode the list